# Plain style tableview: can we display only the required number of rows?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a normal UITableView with its style as plain. I am facing UI issues regarding of it.

If I have only one entry it will show more than one row. One row can be displayed with group style of table but in this option I can't make it as editable.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid these extra cells you can set the tables footer view

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In the plain style, section headers and footers float above the content if the part of a complete section is visible.In plain style it tableView shows number of rows to fit the tableSize with its empty rows.You can make the visible rows to the count you wanted by using CustomCells instead of default cell of the tableView.
Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html